# Is it necessary to specify codecs in HTML5 video?

Tags: html, video

Is it necessary to specify codecs like so in html5 video :

```
<video id="movie" width="320" height="240" preload controls>
<source src="pr6.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=vp8,vorbis" />
<source src="pr6.ogv" type="video/ogg; codecs=theora,vorbis" />
<source src="pr6.mp4" />
</video>
```

Or is it ok to simply do the following :

```
<video id="movie" width="320" height="240" preload controls>
<source src="pr6.webm" type="video/webm" />
<source src="pr6.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
<source src="pr6.mp4" />
</video>
```

The last method seems to work fine in browsers, what is the benefit of the first method? This info is taken from http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html which also should have the mp4 video first in the list for iDevices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No! You just have to make sure to use the supported codecs for the browsers in which your page will be rendered. The browser will ignore the ones it doesn't understand till finds the codec it understands.

Comment: Are there known benefits to this? like faster loading?

Comment: Not really. Browser will not load content of unsupported codecs.

Answer (score 2):

Straight from MDN, `codecs` help browsers make more intelligent decisions, but it's optional

[**Source**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)

Answer (score -1):

It provides security for cross-browser sniffing when it decodes.

[Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video)

Comment: I checked out the link you supplied but I read it different. It says "Due to lack of a common video format, multiple sources is an important technique in order to avoid the need for browser sniffing". So it seems to be talking about sources, not about having to list the specific codec.